# Deploy docker-compose to swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I've got a docker-compose.yml file and if I run docker swarm init I can:

```
$ docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml example
```

And it all works fine.

I gather though that I can't use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm my host isn't part of.

So I started a few Virtualbox instances:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
manager   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.102:2376           v17.05.0-ce
worker1   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v17.05.0-ce
worker2   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376           v17.05.0-ce
```

I've joined the workers to the manager.

```
$ docker-machine ssh worker1 "docker swarm join --token=${worker_token} --listen-addr $(docker-machine ip worker1) --advertise-addr $(docker-machine ip worker1) $(docker-machine ip manager)"
$ docker-machine ssh worker2 "docker swarm join --token=${worker_token} --listen-addr $(docker-machine ip worker2) --advertise-addr $(docker-machine ip worker2) $(docker-machine ip manager)"
```

I wondered if my host could join the swarm, run the stack deploy and leave it?

Attempting to join it fails.

```
Error response from daemon: can't initialize raft node: rpc error: code = 2 desc = could not connect to prospective new cluster member using its advertised address: rpc error: code = 4 desc = context deadline exceeded
```

So my question is, how can I deploy my docker-compose stack to a swarm I'm not a part of? Is copying the file up and running the stack deploy there really the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the best answer I have:

```
$ docker-machine scp docker-compose.yml manager:~/
$ docker-machine ssh manager docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml example
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, not requiring you to copy docker-compose.yml to the manager, would be to send the docker-compose.yml file to the manager on stdin:

```
docker-machine ssh manager docker stack deploy -c - example < docker-compose.yml
```

I provide some examples of this here: [How can I remotely connect to docker swarm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056501/how-can-i-remotely-connect-to-docker-swarm/53358618#53358618)